# Bitcoin core fails to load

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have just loaded the Windows version of Bitcoin Core (v22). But it fails to sync with the network. At around 6 days and 5 hours I see the following:

[image]

Please note that despite 30 years IT experience, I know nothing about crypto.

Comment: Can you post the relevant contents of debug.log? That should provide some more clues about what the issue might be.

Comment: If it takes more than six days to perform the IBD, it seems that either the computer is pretty weak or the hard drive is slow to read/write. Is perhaps the hard drive connected via USB?